# Polymorphic serialization of property

Tags: c#, json, serialization, polymorphism, system.text.json

I'm trying to create a Client library that will allow users to push serialized data to a service.

so I created a class

```
public class Data
{
   public string Prop1 {get; set;}
   public SubData Prop2 {get; set;}
}

public abstract class SubData
{
   public string Prop3 {get; set;}
}
```

I would like to allow users to extend that SubData to add custom properties. but I'm having issues in my Serialization, it doesn't serialize the properties of the extended inner object

```
JsonSerializer.Serialize(data)
```

I know that I could decorate my SubData class with JsonDerivedType attribute, but my problem is that SubData is in a package, and it doesn't know about who will extend it and with what (and it doesn't care)

I don't know if I'm clear what my problem is so here is a full test to replicate:

```
using System.Text.Json;

public class Data
{
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public SubData SubData { get; set; }
}

public abstract class SubData
{
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
}

public class ExtendedSubData : SubData
{
    public string Prop3 { get; set; }

}

var data = new Data
{
    Prop1 = "1",
    SubData = new ExtendedSubData
    {
        Prop2 = "2",
        Prop3 = "3"
    }
};

SerializData(data);

void SerializData(Data data)
{
    var serialized = JsonSerializer.Serialize<object>(data);
    // serialized at this point doesn't contain Prop3 of 
    // ExtendedSubData
}
```

Comment: Please check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializeroptions?view=net-7.0#properties first if your converters, type info resolvers or handlers can "override" default serialization

Comment: See [How to serialize properties of derived classes with System.Text.Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/polymorphism?pivots=dotnet-7-0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative to the custom `JsonConverter`, you can replace the `SubData` property with generic

```cs
public class Data<TSubData>
    where TSubData : SubData
{
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public TSubData SubData { get; set; }
}

string SerializData<TSubData>(Data<TSubData> data)
    where TSubData : SubData
{
    return JsonSerializer.Serialize<object>(data);
}
```

Test it on dotnetfiddle:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/lkOM0Z

Answer (score 1):

The issue you're facing is that the JsonSerializer doesn't know about the existence of ExtendedSubData and its additional properties because it's not explicitly referenced in the serialization process

```
using System;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

public class Data
{
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public SubData SubData { get; set; }
}

public abstract class SubData
{
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
}

public class ExtendedSubData : SubData
{
    public string Prop3 { get; set; }
}

public class SubDataConverter : JsonConverter<SubData>
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type typeToConvert)
    {
        return typeof(SubData).IsAssignableFrom(typeToConvert);
    }

    public override SubData Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, SubData value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, value, value.GetType(), options);
    }
}

var data = new Data
{
    Prop1 = "1",
    SubData = new ExtendedSubData
    {
        Prop2 = "2",
        Prop3 = "3"
    }
};

var options = new JsonSerializerOptions();
options.Converters.Add(new SubDataConverter());

var serialized = JsonSerializer.Serialize(data, options);
Console.WriteLine(serialized);
```

Comment: "Exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' was thrown."